# Add one more space after each new line

Tags: c++, c

How would you do this?
User input a word, after pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> I want to make a new line before each letter and add one more "space" before each letter.

It kinda looks like stairs.

[Pls help.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUF13.png)

Edit: I´ve tried this so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(){

    char text[100], text2[100];
    int i = 0, j = 0, count = 0;

    printf("Vloz text:\n");

    for(i = 0; (text[i]=getchar())!='\n'; i++)
    {
    }        
    text[i] = '\0';
    count = i;

    //vloz space
    for(i = 0; i<count; i++) {
        text2[j] = text[i];
        j++;
        text2[j] = '\n';
        j++;
    }
    text2[j] = '\0';

    printf("%s \n",text2);                

    getche();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You already tried something?

Comment: Please don't post images of text, and especially not *links* to images of text. First of all, links can go stale, making your question worthless. Secondly, it's hard to copy text from an image. And thirdly, not all can actually read text in images (think of people with eye-problems using screen-readers). Instead *copy and paste* the text into the body of the question.

Comment: I´ve edited my post, but don't know how to insert space (i++) on every new line.

Comment: Also, you are clearly programming in C, so please remove the C++ tag, a C++ solution could be vastly different from a C solution.

Comment: @AndrejLavrinčík you wrrite "but don't know how to insert space (i++) on every new line". Format your text as source code and all speces will be preserved.

Comment: http://ideone.com/66wyv6

Comment: _"Pls help.jpg"_ wow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this contradicts what the OP has already done (and I don't know if he has any special requirements, e.g. not using strings), but since the question is tagged with [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), it can be done much simpler:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter the string" << endl;
    string in;
    cin >> in;

    for(string::size_type i = 0; i < in.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << string(i, ' ') << in.at(i) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `fgets()` to read the input.

Remove the `\n` character in the read input because `fgets()` comes with a newline character.

Later print each character in a line

```
char buf[100];
int i,j;
size_t n;
fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin);
n = strlen(buf);
if(n>0 && buf[n-1] == '\n')
buf[n-1] = '\0';

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   j = i;
   while(j--)
   printf(" ");
   printf("%c\n",buf[i]);
}
```

Live Code:http://ideone.com/zfRbO2

Answer (score 1):

here's the code you want ...

```
    #include <iostream>
    #define N 20
    using namespace std;
main()
{
  char input[N];
  cout<<"enter a word:\n";
  cin>>input;
  for(int i=0,j=1;i<N;i++,j++)
  {
    for(k=0;k<j;k++) cout<<" ";
    cout<<input[i]<<endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Technically that's not a valid C++ program, the `main` function *must* be declared to return an `int`. Also, why use arrays that can overflow when there is `std::string`?

Comment: i know what you're saying but compilers like Dev don't use exactly the standard form of C++ ... anyway ... thanks for your edit ! :)